# Подскажите решение (Галерею) по Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста какое-нибудь готовое решение... плагин... Настройки продукта, чтобы сделать страницу с Галереей!
Уже очень много времени на это убил, но нормального варианта не нашел!
Требуется просто загрузить картинки на страницу и чтобы внизу каждой картинки было подписано название полностью.
После некоторых действий выскакивает ошибка 500, приходится удалять галерею и ставить другое решение и т.д. Очень устал от этого) Помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Использовал много вариантов и все не очень!
Попробовал стандартную галерею и всё хорошо.